# Need some coding to input inside my image?

Tags: python

this is what my program should look like:

[image: Expected]

```
def main():

    from graphics import GraphWin, Point, Rectangle

    win= GraphWin("Apartment Displayer",700,400)

    p1=Point(40,50)

    p2=Point(100,130)

    rec=Rectangle(p1,p2)

    rec.setFill("cyan")

    rec.draw(win)

    p3=Point(100,30)

    p4=Point(280,130)

    rec=Rectangle(p3,p4)

    rec.setFill("yellow")

    rec.draw(win)

    p5=Point(280,30)

    p6=Point(550,130)

    rec=Rectangle(p5,p6)

    rec.setFill("tan3")

    rec.draw(win)

    p7=Point(75,130)

    p8=Point(200,320)

    rec=Rectangle(p7,p8)

    rec.setFill("green3")

    rec.draw(win)

    p9=Point(200,130)

    p10=Point(220,320)

    rec=Rectangle(p9,p10)

    rec.setFill("tan")

    rec.draw(win)

    p11=Point(220,130)

    p12=Point(550,225)

    rec=Rectangle(p11,p12)

    rec.setFill("cyan3")

    rec.draw(win)

    p13=Point(220,225)

    p14=Point(275,320)

    rec=Rectangle(p13,p14)

    rec.setFill("yellow3")

    rec.draw(win)

    p15=Point(275,225)

    p16=Point(550,320)

    rec=Rectangle(p15,p16)

    rec.setFill("green")

    rec.draw(win)

    p17=Point(550,30)

    p18=Point(570,320)

    rec=Rectangle(p17,p18)

    rec.setFill("tan")

    rec.draw(win)

    s=input("close Window?")

    win.close()

main()
```

This is what i have, but don't know how to put the names inside my rectangles as shown in my link. Please can someone help me???

Thank You...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is use `Text`

```
Text(Point(60, 60), "kitchen").draw(win)
```

I don't have windows with me at the moment, but I think this is the quickest hack.

Furthermore, please take a look at this [documentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf&ei=0iOOT_veEoXf0QGmqrGSDw&usg=AFQjCNEMXOo4ZsLRgivN1xwQatTSVyqXuA&sig2=UYeS-OBpZlJDZJeOkjpwGw) and go to `3.7 Text Methods`

Comment: NP. Look at the documentation (it's a link). Go to page 4 `3.7 Text Methods` you will see the methods available such as `setSize(12)` for font or `setStyle('bold')` for style.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of what it is you're trying to do here, beyond draw the layout of a floor of a building. Perhaps take a look into [PyGame](http://pygame.org/news.html), where drawing rects, and rendering fonts would be just as simple as what you are doing here, and you'd be able to get more help, as it's a fairly well known library.